# How to implement the tensor product of two layers in Keras/Tf

Tags: tensorflow, keras, linear-algebra

I'm trying to set up a DNN for classification and at one point I want to take the tensor product of a vector with itself. I'm using the Keras functional API at the moment but it isn't immediately clear that there is a layer that does this already.

I've been attempting to use a Lambda layer and numpy in order to try this, but it's not working. 
Doing a bit of googling reveals 
`tf.linalg.LinearOperatorKronecker`, which does not seem to work either.

Here's what I've tried:
I have a layer called `part_layer` whose output is a single vector (rank one tensor).

```py
keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x_array: np.outer(x_array, x_array),) ( part_layer) )
```

Ideally I would want this to to take a vector of the form `[1,2]` and give me `[[1,2],[2,4]]`.
But the error I'm getting suggests that the `np.outer` function is not recognizing its arguments:

```py
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_keras_history
```

Any ideas on what to try next, or if there is a simple function to use?

Comment: Try `tf.tensordot(x_array, x_array, axes=0)` instead of using Numpy's `np.outer`.

Comment: Wouldn't this give me a scalar rather than a rank two tensor?

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé Please re-state your answer - I managed to fix the issue via using a reshape layer afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tf.tensordot(x_array, x_array, axes=0)` to achieve what you want. For example, the expression `print(tf.tensordot([1,2], [1,2], axes=0))` gives the desired result: `[[1,2],[2,4]]`.

Keras/Tensorflow needs to keep an history of operations applied to tensors to perform the optimization. Numpy has no notion of history, so using it in the middle of a layer is not allowed. `tf.tensordot` performs the same operation, but keeps the history.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this does not work. For instance, while the input to this layer has shape (None, 5), the output has shape (None, 5, None, 5) rather than (None, 5, 5) as I wanted.

Comment: Actually, tried this again using `x = Lambda(lambda x_array: tf.tensordot(x_array, x_array, axis=0) ) ( x )` and then applying a transpose layer via `x = Lambda(lambda x_array: tf.transpose(x_array, perm=[0,2,1,3]) )(x)` to fix the above mentioned output issue, and finally slicing via `x = Lambda(lambda x_array: x_array[0,:, :, :] )( x )`

Answer (score 2):

You can use two operations:

If you want to consider the batch size you can use [the Dot function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dot)

Otherwise, you can use the [the dot function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/dot)

In both case the code should look like this:

```
dot_lambda = lambda x_array: tf.keras.layers.dot(x_array, x_array)
# dot_lambda = lambda x_array: tf.keras.layers.Dot(x_array, x_array)
keras.layers.Lambda(dot_lamda)( part_layer)
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks - I got a previous answer to work but I will try this in my next iteration of the network.